# Get the host name when running ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

Learning to work with ansible –
I need to prepare the servers for cluster deployment.

- install the same set of programs on all nodes, and so on.
  There are no problems with this part, everything works out.
  I do it via ansible-playbook. When on each node it is necessary in the file
  **/etc/sysconfig/network**

Write the following

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=nn1
```

Where NETWORKING=yes
common to all
and HOSTNAME=nn1 individual for each host in the hostname part

I do it this way

**/etc/ansible/hosts**

```
[cluster1]
nn1
dd1
dd2
dd3
dd4
```

Here is the part of playbook.yml where I try to make the changes I need

```
- name: sysconfig -> network
  tags: wr_net_yes
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sysconfig/network
    line: "NETWORKING=yes"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'

- name: sysconfig -> network
  tags: wr_net_host
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sysconfig/network
    line: "HOSTNAME={{ network_wr }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
```

This part
**tags: wr_net_yes**
**succeeds**

And I can't do it this part
tags: wr_net_host

Maybe some advice, help?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via ansible variables, like:

```
- name: sysconfig -> network
  tags: wr_net_host
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sysconfig/network
    line: "HOSTNAME={{ inventory_hostname }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but it gave an error and climbed somewhere in the other direction…

Thanks!
It worked!